# Imagemagick error using overlapcrop on Window with Cygwin

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I am using *Imageimagick* to crop arieal images in equal sizes.
Searching Google *imagemagick* tutorials led me to [Fred Weinhaus scripts](http://im.snibgo.com/cygwin.htm#installim) tutorial which I followed. When I am passing the command on *bash* or cmd based on syntax given in this [website](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php) (`bash /fullpathto/scriptname.sh` with arguments /fullpathto/inputimage /fullpathto/outputimage)

I am getting error

```
$ overlapcrop -s 128 -o 50% -m matrix -M -L \
  -R 'F:\bash\top_potsdam_2_10_RGB' 'F:\bash\o.jpg'

error Invalid Parameter - F:\bash\top_potsdam_2_10_RGB
```

> FILE F:\bash\top_potsdam_2_10_RGB DOES NOT EXIST OR IS NOT AN ORDINARY FILE, NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE

Even if we set the directory in the path, we get the same error:

```
$ overlapcrop -s 128 -o 50% -m matrix -M -L -R top_potsdam_2_10_RGB.png o.png
```

--[Screenshots of imagemagick --help and convert --help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/julUo.png)
[error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjHxW.png)

Comment: it seems you have a problem with the PATH. What is the output of `which convert` ?

Comment: Have you tried to install the cygwin `Imagemagick` package ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows is useless when it comes to quoting, so maybe try escaping the `%` sign by adding a second one or a caret (`^`) in front of it.

Also, try removing the `F:` from the paths and try putting the files in the current directory in case the slashes are causing errors.

Finally, you may have your PATH set incorrectly so that when the script executes the `convert` command it finds the Windows utility that converts filesystems to NTFS rather than the ImageMagick utility that converts images.

Try running:

```
convert /?
```

and seeing if you get an error/help message from Windows CONVERT.EXE or something from ImageMagick. If you get the Windows one, your PATH is incorrect and you need to put the directory where you installed ImageMagick ahead (in front of) `C:\WINDOWS\System32` or wherever Windows CONVERT.EXE lives and restart your Command Prompt window.

Comment: I have done every thing as steps provided by this website http://im.snibgo.com/cygwin.htm#installim .I have a new version of Imagemagick .In this convert.exe is not there.Please tell me is this syntax is correct to do cropping with this overlapcrop script

Comment: Ok, I guess you installed v7 and did not check/tick the box entitled **"Install legacy commands"** in the installation. Try changing all occurrences of `identify` in Fred's script to `magick identify` and all occurrences of `convert` to `magick`. Or install again and tick that box this time.

Comment: I install cygwin with packages gnuplot and bc and imagemagick is installed seperately (from official Imagemagick binary release).In the whole process I didnot installed anything like v7......When I am giving the command overlapcrop --help then it is runing and showing all options.But When trying to crop then it is showing the error. Thankyou

Comment: Ok, please click `edit` under your question and paste the following commands and their output... `magick -help` and `convert -help`

Comment: So, the way you are currently set up is that `convert` runs Windows `convert` for converting filesystems and not ImageMagick `convert`. You have `magick` available instead. So you need to edit Fred's script and change all instances of `convert` to `magick` and all instances of `identify` to `magick identify`

Comment: I have done this and now it is not showing error.But After execution of the command  two .bak file is created (overlapcrop.bak and overlapcrop.sh.bak) in the same directory but there is no output pngfile (o.png).Thanku

Comment: There seems to be a `montage` in there too, so that needs to become `magick montage`

Comment: Read user snibgo's comments about using Unix file paths on Cygwin at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=25910. Changing convert to magick should not be needed. But I will have to fix the script if it has montage in it to be magick montage.

Comment: I have edited overlapcrop to fix the issue with montage.

Comment: $ bash overlapcrop -s 120 -o 50% -m sequential -u -M -L -R top_potsdam_2_10_RGB.png o.png (command) and error---
Usage: magick.exe tool [ {option} | {image} ... ] {output_image}
Usage: magick.exe [ {option} | {image} ... ] {output_image}
       magick.exe [ {option} | {image} ... ] -script {filename} [ {script_args} ...]
       magick.exe -help | -version | -usage | -list {option}

Error: Invalid argument or not enough arguments

Comment: Now it is showing different error after doing all this.Is there any argument which is missed in above command.

Comment: Please don't put complex stuff in comments- it is hard to read. Better to click `edit` under your question and add material in there where everyone can see it without looking through comments and where it is properly formatted. Thank you.

Comment: I think we are maybe talking at cross-purposes so I'll keep quiet and let Fred help you as he is the author and more skilled/familiar. I'm sure he'll get you sorted out.